# Is the location of SSH keys on Windows fixed?

Tags: windows, ssh

I read an article: [Determine whether you've already generated SSH keys](http://ist.berkeley.edu/as-ag/tools/howto/ssh-key-exchange-win.html#keys-generated-check) which says that SSH in Windows, keys stored are in `C:\Documents and Settings\userName\Application Data\SSH\UserKeys\`, but I have found the keys to be in `C:\Documents and Settings\userName\Application Data\.SSH \`.   Is there a setting to determine where to put these keys or am I reading the wrong documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using the same [SSH Tectia Client 6.1](http://www.ssh.com/support/documentation/manuals/)?  According the the [Tectia Users' Manuals](http://www.ssh.com/documents/30/SSHTectiaClient_UserManual61.pdf) the default directory is  `%APPDATA%\SSH\UserKeys` which is the directory cited in the guide you read.